# How to decouple object properties based on their extended interfaces typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an interface that extends multiple interfaces

```
interface A extends B, C {
  a1: type;
  a2: type;
  a3: type;
}

interface B {
  b1: type;
  b2: type;
  b3: type;
}

interface C {
  c1: type;
  c2: type;
  c3: type;
}
```

The server responses with A and I have separate objects of type B and C. What I want to do is decouple it using Types so that I won't have to do

```
a:A = response
b = { b1: a.b1, b2: a.b2 ... }
c = { c1: a.c1, c2: a.c2 ... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use an assert type

If you do something like

```
returnedObject as B
```

This will basically extract the B part of the object as long as it’s compliant. Meaning it needs to have all the properties defined in the B contract. And this is true for C also if you do

```
returnedObject as C
```

Basically type assertion is a kind of casting but in compile time. Not on runtime like a regular casting.

You are telling TypeScript that you have total control on the object type being returned and you know exactly the format of what’s being returned.

Comment: Yes, there is no such thing as runtime casting since there are no types in JavaScript

Comment: Handles assertion. But in this way, it does type assertion but not extraction of specific keys.